# using function on colum name with aes_string in ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some graphs and the column name is changing within a loop.
I also want to apply a `log2()` onto this column so my plan was to do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y.bla=c(2,3,4,5,6),
                 y.blub=c(5,4,3,2,1))
for(label in c('bla','blub')) {
  g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x='x', y=paste0('y.', label))) + geom_point()
  print(g)
}

for(label in c('bla','blub')) {
  g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x='x', y=log2(paste0('y.', label)))) + geom_point()
  print(g)
}
```

But actually, the `log2` function can not handle the string.
Is there a workaround?

I want to do this within the loop and not with facet wrap or something like this, since I append these single graphs to a list of different figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few ways of doing this. I'd extract elements from the dataframe by name and transform them before plotting.

```
for(label in c('bla','blub')) {

  temp_var <- log2(df[[paste0('y.', label)]])

  g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y= temp_var)) + geom_point()
  print(g)
}
```

Comment: Hah, that was to easy! I expected R will complain because it is no data frame or something... Love it!